# Chrome memory leak when hiding or showing images

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, memory-leaks

Greetings from a long time lurker but frequent user of this site.  Great info here.  I am working on my first real web project and learning as I go.

This is a medical application that sometimes has to show alarm icons (divs containing images) to draw attention to patients that may be in trouble.  I have been using the following JS/jQuery code to show the appropriate icon by using css classes.  My css skills are not great, so it is likely that this could be done more efficiently, but that is not the point of my question.

When I run the following code for 128 different patients at 500 msec intervals (using a setTimeout after each update), the Chrome render process eats memory at around 50MB/hour (per Task Manager or the SysInternals Process Explorer).  However, the Chrome dev tools do not show any increases in memory usage or DOM node count.  The heap snapshots do not show any significant changes over time.  But if I comment out this part, the "leak" goes away.

What am I missing?

```
//  Show appropriate alarm icon, or hide all
iconClass = null;
if (this.Status && displayMode === 'RealTime') {
    if (this.Status.Alarm === 'Active') {
        flashState = ((this.drawTickCount % 4) < 2);
        iconClass = (flashState) ? 'alarmOn' : 'alarmOff';
    }
    else if (this.Status.Alarm === 'Paused') {
        iconClass = 'alarmPaused';
    }
}
//  Hide all icons
this.div.find('div.alarmIcon').css('visibility', 'hidden');
//  Show the active icon, if any
if (iconClass) {
    this.div.find('div.' + iconClass).css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the only thing your script does?

Comment: got a jsfiddle.net example that shows this happening?

Comment: I don't know if it is causing the memory leak, but you are making both `iconClass` and `flashState` global variables, which is bad practice.  Stick a `var` in front of them when you declare them, `var iconClass = null;` and `var flashState = ((this.drawTickCount % 4) < 2);`

Comment: Just didn't include enough code.  They are var'd at the top of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to leave this as a comment, but it got too long for the comment box.

Chrome was plagued by [image-related memory leaks](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142) for a long time, but I'm not sure that's the problem you're seeing here.

These are all just shots in the dark, but here are some things you can try:

- Instead of animating the flashing alarm icon on a timer, use an animated gif. If gif is no good (you need more than 256 colors, or an alpha channel) try flashing it with a CSS transition/animation.
- Add some logic to check if anything has actually changed before modifying the DOM. This will at least help performance, since you don't have to constantly reflow the document (assuming you animated the flashing alarm without constant document modifications).
- If it's still leaking, try getting rid of the jQuery stuff in this part of the code. It may or may not be causing the leak, but if you remove it and the leak's still there, at least you'll know for sure that it wasn't causing it.

I came to the conclusion a few years ago that Chrome wasn't suitable for long-running wallboard type applications because of memory leaks, but the situation may have improved since then. If nothing else, you could try having the app kill the tab and start a new one every hour or so. Good luck.

Comment: dag nabbit - thanks, good tips.  I am planning on some work arounds similar what you suggest, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.  I have been ditching jQuery in the hot parts of the app just in case.